# Getting the substring between a substring at the end and before it

Tags: python

I currently have a string of the format:

```
/Users/me/Documents/Project/zh-Hant-TW.lproj
```

I want to isolate the string between the word `.lproj` and the forward slash `/` just before it. The result should be `zh-Hant-TW`. So far I am trying to use:

```
print(myString[len("/"):-len(".lproj")])
```

However this is picking the very first `/` and the result is:

`Users/me/Documents/Project/zh-Hant-TW`

Not sure how to go about this. Tried reversing the string and working backwards but that just came out a mess. Any tips or pointers on how to do this? Thanks

Comment: `os.path.splitext` can do half the job for you. I take it you can guess which half. One way to get the other half done is `stem.split('/')` which gives you a list of all the bits between slashes. Where `stem` is what you get in the first step.

Comment: `"/Users/me/Documents/Project/zh-Hant-TW.lproj".split("/")[-1].split(".")[0]`?

Answer (score 1):

If it's an actual path, you can always use:

```
import os

print(os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(myString))[0])
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import os

print os.path.basename('/Users/me/Documents/Project/zh-Hant-TW.lproj').split('.')[0]

>> zh-Hant-TW
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use python's `os.path` library, which can help you handle path related problems elegantly.

```
import os
basename = os.path.basename(myString)
filename = os.path.splitext(filename)[0]
```

Answer (score 0):

Since there are already several answers using the `os` module, here is one using regular expressions...

```
import re

path = '/Users/me/Documents/Project/zh-Hant-TW.lproj'

results = re.findall(r'(?<=Project\/)(.*).lproj', path')[0]

# results = 'zh-Hant-TW'
```